# Event listener for 'devicemotion' not running function

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to assign motion to 3 variables outside the event listener, but the function inside my event listener doesn't even seem to be running. I've tried checking it like this too:

```
if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
    console.log("devicemotion was defined");
};
```

The console logged the text, but not this text:

```
var x, y, z;
var interval;
var arr = {'data':[]};
var ON = false;


window.addEventListener("devicemotion", function(event){
        x = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
        y = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
        z = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;
        console.log(x,y,z)
        }
    ,true);
```

**Edit:**
This script code is in the bottom of a html file located in a templates directory.
The html is running on Django.

The whole script(Some is commented out because the event listener isn't working)

```
<!--Clientside script-->
<script>
var x, y, z, alpha, gamma, beta;
var interval;
var arr = {'data':[]};
var ON = false;


window.addEventListener("devicemotion", function(event){
        //x = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
        //y = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
        //z = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;
        console.log(event)
        }
    ,true);
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event){
        alpha = event.alpha;
        gamma = event.gamma;
        beta = event.beta;
        }
    ,true);


//Events that are running always
if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
    console.log("devicemotion was defined");
};

if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
  console.log("GyroScope was defined");
};

$('input').on('click', function(){
    if(ON==true){
        ON=false;
    } else {
        ON=true;
    }
});

//Main function,
//Creates list of sensor data.
function mainFunc(){ /*
    if(ON=true){
        interval = setInterval(() => {
            arr['data'] = arr['data'].concat([x,y,z,alpha,gamma,beta]);
            if(arr['data'].length >=30){
            send();
            console.log(arr);
            }
            console.log([x,y,z,alpha,gamma,beta]);
        }, 200);
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    */
}

//Ajax get request
//Checks for a response and animates the indicator accordingly.
function send(){
    pack = arr['data'];
    arr['data'].length = 0;

    $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'detect' %}",
                data: arr,
                async: false,
                success: function(data){
                    if (data==true){
                        $('#indicator').fadeIn('slow');
                        $('#indicator').fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                }
    })

};
</script>
```

Comment: Try `console.log(event);`to see if the event is even handled.

Comment: What device are you actually testing on? Could be the device itself not firing the event.

Comment: @Melbourne2991 I have it on my laptop, it's running Django, but I'm certain it has devicemotion event present

Comment: @connexo I tried inserting your line inside the event listener function. But there's no response

Comment: @eitroo sorry I don't mean to doubt you, but I am curious about what makes you certain it supports this event?

Comment: @Melbourne2991 I've visited another website with this event, and it ran alright I think. My laptop is a laptop/tablet, so there's definitely motion sensors on it.

Comment: In that case could you show the broader context of this code...where does it live?

Comment: @Melbourne2991 What do you mean aexctly?

Comment: Is this code living in an html file? A script? Could you show us the rest of the file?

Comment: Does the deviceorientation event fire?

Comment: @Melbourne2991 No it doesn't. But it's dedicated to phones, which have needed sensors

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the above. I would double check that it definitely did work on the other site and try and see what they are doing differently - also try it in different browsers.